# Can you encrypt an encrypted string over and over again?

Tags: php, encryption

I was wondering if you can use md5 over and over again, or use sha1 over and over again, for example:

```
$pass = md5($pass);
$pass = sha1($pass);
$pass = md5($pass);
$pass = md5($pass);
```

and still have it **work**? So it encrypts the encrypted string again and again because I wanted to make a seriously encrypted password system so that nobody can hack, and I am worried this extra algorithm I'm creating will work or not.?

Comment: what you are doing is hashing, not encryption.

Answer (score 5):

If you're trying to hash passwords, look into [scrypt](http://www.tarsnap.com/scrypt.html). Don't use anything else, and definitely don't roll your own system.

Comment: "Don't use anything else". How about bcrypt?

Comment: @GregS: bcrypt works too, especially if `crypt` compatibility on OpenBSD is required, but scrypt is better, because it not only parameterises the work complexity (as bcrypt does), but also the memory usage required (which ups the cost of massively parallel hardware crackers).

Answer (score 3):

Neither MD5 nor SHA1 are encryption algorithms; they're one-way hash functions. Nobody can "hack" either, in the sense that they're not reversible; the original information is lost. What one *can* do is try to forge a different text that gives the same hash; repeated hashing will make this neither easier nor harder.

Comment: I don't know because I googled a "md5 decrypter", and websites, for example, [this page](http://md5decryption.com/) actually can successfully decrypt md5 encryptions, so I was a bit worried

Comment: @Ninjiangstar: If you're using MD5 to hash your passwords, you're doing it wrong. :-)

Comment: what should I use? but if I actually did encrypt a string over and over again, would it actually work?

Comment: @Ninjiangstar: 10 years ago, if you hashed your password >1000 times, it might have worked. These days, you need to do better. Use [scrypt](http://www.tarsnap.com/scrypt.html), and don't try to roll your own solution.

Comment: @Ninjiangstar: what that is, is a database of *plaintext/hash* pairs; if you give them a hash, it will look up plaintext(s) that have that same hash. Now, that sounds scary, but you have to realize that there are over 11 million combinations of just 5 lower-case ASCII characters. If you were to require passwords to be any 10 characters out of the 128-character ASCII set, then their database would need to hold 10^21 (ten to the 21st power) entries to match that; that's over 100,000 *exabytes* of storage. Don't worry -- your passwords are safe as long as they're not dictionary words.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your idea works and is in fact a very good idea if properly implemented. See [wikipedia's article on key stretching for some pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_stretching) on what has already been done.

However, I would not use MD5, but use a hash function for which no algorithm for finding collisions fast are known (e.g. SHA256). Doing so allows to use the results from the paper "Secure Applications of Low-Entropy Keys" by Kelsey, Schneier, Hall and Wagner. In particular Theorem 1 shows some security properties if the hash function used is strong collision resistant. And it is always nice to have some theoretical backing of a cryptographic protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Hashing once is equally secure as hashing many times.  It's a fact of mathematical encryption algorithms.

What you really want to do is add a [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) to your algorithm.

In addition, hashing a password many times can result in [cryptographic collisions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_%28computer_science%29) which actually makes the encryption LESS secure.

Basically, this is not a wise design decision, nor is it good practice.

### edit #1

In addition, use an algorithm that hasn't already been severely cracked.
I prefer [whirlpool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whirlpool_%28cryptography%29), which is very strong.  Combined with a salt, it's nearly impenetrable.

Comment: There _is_ a decent reason to hash a password many (>1000) times, which is called "[stretching](http://chargen.matasano.com/chargen/2007/9/7/enough-with-the-rainbow-tables-what-you-need-to-know-about-s.html)": it makes each password cracking attempt take longer. However, the proper defence against that these days is to use scrypt (see my answer).

Comment: Just to be sure we're on the same page, rainbow tables are not the weakest link in the chain. You need to use an algorithm that takes a long time to try each password, to deter automated password crackers.

Comment: You answer is contrary to well-established cryptographic principles for password hashing. Can you justify this?

Comment: @greg I'm not sure what you mean.  Salting is ALWAYS a good idea, and every time you hash a string, it decreases the input pool from (essentially) infinite to whatever the output of the previous algorithm was, which effectively increases the likelihood of a collision which completely ruins the effect of hashing a password to begin with.  MD5 has been cracked to hell and back, and SHA1 is on it's way.  How exactly is my answer contrary to hashing principles?  I've provided a little data that, given a very short amount of googling, is valid.  Can you justify **your** comment?